# Subsets of continuous functions are continuous, but what about in this case?

Tags: real-analysis

I keep finding proofs discussing how subsets of continuous functions are continuous, but I’m puzzled because what if my continuous function is, for example, y=x, and I make my subset of x the even integers. Then as far as I can tell I would have just created a discontinuous subset from a continuous function.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: What is a discontinuous set?

Comment: I think the standard phrase is "restrictions of continuous functions", rather than "subsets of continuous functions". (unless I have misunderstood your scenario.)

Comment: When the domain of a function is not an interval, there is a (topological) definition of continuity that's actually easier to satisfy at the "holes" or "gaps" of the domain. It becomes much different from our intuition of a continuous function (on an interval) as being one whose graph has no breaks in it. For example, *every* function whose domain is the even integers is continuous.

Comment: Thanks! That helped make sense of what I was seeing. To clarify what I was asking about I’m going to attempt to cite the original discussion that I read below:

Comment: @MISC {1773085,
    TITLE = {Subsets of continuous functions are also continuous},
    AUTHOR = {Ben (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/330672/ben)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773085 (version: 2016-05-05)},
    EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773085},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773085}
}